# Installing Roof - What else should be done?

Tags: repair, insulation, roof, ventilation

When installing a new roof, what other work would be convenient to do? Since I'm having a new roof installed, I'm curious if there is something I would regret not doing in a few years.

Potentially convenient:

- Chimney work
- Roof vent installation
- Insulation
- Bathroom vent
- Running electrical cable for a sky light
- New gutters

Comment: Where are you on this planet? How much ground snow load do you get per year, on average?

Comment: If your chimney needs pointing, get it done before the new roof. If the bathroom vent doesn't exist (or has a woefully small pipe), getting a new vent installed by the roofers (and connected later by whoever does the fan work) would be good. Now would be an okay time to assess your plumbing vent pipes and ensure that they aren't galvanized with a very short remaining lifespan. If you wanted electric to a skylight, it might be slightly more convenient when the sheathing is exposed, but that's not a given. The rest of your list doesn't really have a gantt chart type of relationship to roofing.

Comment: What kind of skylight requires power? Unfortunately, what work _should_ be done is really opinion based, which doesn't sit well at SE. Logically, any work that requires access to the attic/roof area but would be easier to do without the roof in the way (if they're doing a full tear-off) might _make sense_, but only you can determine if it should be done or not.

Comment: Unfortunately, any answer to this question will be a matter of opinion. Please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.